# Foreign Key Syntax

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have created Teacher table first and its description is

```
   mysql> desc teacher;
   +--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
   | Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
   +--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
   | TEACHER_ID   | varchar(3)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
   | TEACHER_NAME | varchar(40) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
   +--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

After i have created a new table as following .My need is that in the following table i want to use `TEACHER_ID` as foreign key.I have written the following.I dnt know whether it is wrong means syntactically.But i didn't get any error...

```
 mysql> CREATE TABLE SUB_MCA_TY
->  (SUB_ID VARCHAR(4) PRIMARY KEY,
->  SUB_NAME VARCHAR(30),
-> TEACHER_ID VARCHAR(3) REFERENCES TEACHER(TEACHER_ID));
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"Inline" foreign keys are *always* silently ignored by MySQL, even with InnoDB (welcome to the wonderful consistent world of MySQL...)

You need to change it into an explicit constraint after the columns:

```
CREATE TABLE SUB_MCA_TY
(
   SUB_ID VARCHAR(4) PRIMARY KEY,
   SUB_NAME VARCHAR(30),
   TEACHER_ID VARCHAR(3),
   foreign key (TEACHER_ID) REFERENCES TEACHER(TEACHER_ID)
);
```

[Quote from the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html):

> *MySQL does not recognize or support “inline REFERENCES specifications” (as defined in the SQL standard) where the references are defined as part of the column specification*